# Sending User Registration Emails to the email inbox of the User using YII framework

Tags: php, email, smtp, yii

I am developing web application using Yii framework. currently i am in the process of implementing log in system of the application. i want to send a email to the Users email address containing link to confirm the registration using this link. could any body who has done such a implementation before using Yii framework or it's extension could share ideas with me. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple, I suggest you make it yourself, I think it will save a lot of time than study how to implement and use a new extension.

Add columns CHECK_SUM, STATUS to your user table. CHECK_SUM is used to store the encrypted value or any random values could use to check a user, and column STATUS default to 0, when the email address is checked set it to 1 to make this account able to login.

When users submit their registration forms:

```
function encrypt($pswd)
{
   ....//make your own encrypt method to store uses' password
}
//suppose your user model is Users
$users->email=$_POST['email'];
$users->pswd=encrypt($_POST['pswd']);
...
//here comes the customized part
$users->check_sum=sha1($_POST['email'].time());//or other method to make a safe random string
if($users->save())
{
  $to=...;
  $subject=...;
  //suppose your reg page is in reg controller.
  $msg='please visit <a href="domain.com/reg/check?sum='.$users->check_sum.'">this url</a> to finish registration';
  mail($to,$subject,$msg,$header);
}
```

In your reg controller, add:

```
    public function actionCheck()
    {
     if(isset($_GET['sum']))
     {
      $c=new CDbCriteria;
      $c->condition="check_sum=:i";
      $c->params=array($i=>$_GET['sum']);
      $user=Users::model()->find($c);
      if($user)
      {
       $user->status=1;
       $user->save();
       $this->redirect('http://...');
      }
     }
    }
```

This is my solution.

Comment: could you explain me what are u referring to as reg controller

Comment: reg controller is used to create url like domain.com/reg/xxx(here we need is domain.com/reg/check ). If url format is not important to you, you can add that actionCheck() function in any controller(e.g. user controller(url will become x.com/user/check) or which your registration page belongs to)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is an extension for user management [yii-user](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/), it is a module with many features including registration. You can always refer to the source code to develop your own registration system.